# Validate uniqueness nested model params

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_countries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_countries, reject_if: :all_blank
  validate :user_countries
end

class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_countries
  has_many :users, :through => :user_countries
end
```

In a the user creation form I can create user_countries too. How I can validate in server the uniqueness of country_id in user_countries. A user has many countries: France, United State... but not for example: France and France.

I've added this to user_countries.. but it don't work:

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :country_id, allow_blank: false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the `user_country` model.

```
class UserCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :country
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :country_id, allow_blank: false
end
```

Also, you need to create a migration like below to add ***unique indexes*** on database level.

```
add_index :user_countries, [ :user_id, :country_id ], :unique => true
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Although it's raising ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique Exception.. how I rescue it? I have added the validates_uniqueness_of  in userCountry...